# How can I set a specific Region Format inside of my app and override the devices Region Format in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, regional-settings

I have a basic calculator app and it doesn't handle percentages properly in regions where a decimal point "." is used as the comma separator and a comma "," is used to mark the radix point. I am working on a fix for this but in the meantime I am wondering if when my app launches, I could override the Region Format set in the devices settings app and force a specific Region Format, only for my app.

Is this possible? Thank you for your time with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this, I suggest you look at NSNumberFormatter and NSNumber to do it the right away. For example, this should work regardless of the device's regional settings.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *test = [formatter numberFromString:@"1,000,000"];
```

Also look at the other functionality provided by NSNumberFormatter. This seems like a more elegant way to do it than what you're trying.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was using NSNumberFormatter and did figure out the fix before looking at this but I am glad I did it correctly. I did have it set already to NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle but I didn't specifically "setDecimalSeparator" to "." so in certain regions when the user tapped "." it was changed to "," and created a problem with the calculation. Now by setting the separator programmatically it remains "." regardless of region. Thanks again.